# immediate piping with python

Tags: python, unix, pipe

I have two files first of which is fizz

```
#!/usr/bin/python                                                         
import time

print 'started'
time.sleep(3)
print 'ended'
```

next of which is bar

```
#!/usr/bin/python                                                         
import sys

for line in sys.stdin:
    print line
```

When I run the command `./fizz | ./bar` I expect it to print `started` then wait 3 seconds and print `ended`, but what really happends is that it prints `started` and `ended` at the same time after 3 seconds. Is there a way to get my desired behavior? Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Good question. It is a little harder than it should.

The issue is indeed in `bar`, specifically `sys.stdin` being buffered. I tried opening `sys.stdin` with a smaller buffer size and using `python -u` but that didn't work. The manpage has this to say:

> ```
>    -u     Force  stdin,  stdout  and  stderr to be totally unbuffered.  On
>           systems where it matters, also put stdin, stdout and  stderr  in
>           binary  mode.   Note  that there is internal buffering in xread‐
>           lines(), readlines() and file-object  iterators  ("for  line  in
>           sys.stdin")  which  is  not  influenced by this option.  To work
>           around this, you will want to use "sys.stdin.readline()"  inside
>           a "while 1:" loop.
> ```

In the end this is what worked for me:

```
#!/usr/bin/python                                                   
import sys 
import os

while True:
    line = sys.stdin.readline()
    if not line:
        break
    sys.stdout.write(line) # or print, doesn't matter.
```

Answer (score 6):

Now that it is clear that the problem is on the receiving side, I present an alternative which I like to use:

```
#!/usr/bin/python                                                   
import sys 
import os

for line in iter(sys.stdin.readline, ''):
    sys.stdout.write(line) # \n included in line
```

`iter(func, sentinel)` calls `func()` for each iteration and ends if the function result `== sentinel`.

Answer (score 1):

There are two problems:

1. `print "something"` in `./foo` doesn't flush its stdout buffer if it is redirected (to the pipe in this case) i.e., when [stdout is not connected a tty-like device](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=isatty#file.isatty) e.g., to an interactive console
2. `for line in sys.stdin:` might try to read several lines at a time

You can fix it as follows:

```
$ PYTHONUNBUFFERED=1 ./foo | ./bar
```

Where `./bar`:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import sys

for line in iter(sys.stdin.readline, ''):
    print line,
```

i.e., make `./foo`'s stdout unbuffered ([`-u` option](http://docs.python.org/using/cmdline.html?highlight=unbuffered#cmdoption-u)) and read input in `./bar` line by line as suggested in [@Eduardo Ivanec's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9756328/4279).

As alternative you could call `sys.stdout.flush()` in `./foo` instead of making its stdout unbuffered as suggested in [@kev's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9756148/4279).